# Solving 1D second order ODE BVP with dataset

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, matlab, boundary-value-problem, discrete-calculus

I am solving a second-order ODE similar to the following equation:
$$
y''+y=f(x),
\\
y(0)=0,~~ y(π/2)=2,
$$
`xmesh = linspace(0,π/2,5);`

If I use f(x) as a function of x such as x^2 or sin(x) or ... my code works and has no issue. However, in my case f(x) is a dataset in which its length is equal to the length of xmesh, and I cannot solve it.
I am wondering if there is a way to use available MATLAB functions to solve my case.
Here is my MATLAB code.

```
clear all
close all
clc

xmesh = linspace(0, pi/2, 5);
solinit = bvpinit(xmesh, @guess);

f = 2*xmesh;% I produce this dataset which is similar to my case

bvpfcn_x=@(x,y)[y(2);-y(1)+2*x];% {when I consider f=2x, there is no error and matlab calculate it.} 
%bvpfcn_x=@(x,y)[y(2);-y(1)+f];% when I consider f(x) as a dataset, then there is an error.

sol = bvp4c(bvpfcn_x, @bcfcn, solinit);
plot(sol.x, sol.y(1,:), '-o')

function res = bcfcn(ya,yb)% boundary conditions
  res = [ya(1);yb(1)-2];
end

function g = guess(x)% initial guess for y and y'
  g = [sin(x);cos(x)];
end
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given a function table, and you need a nice guess for values at arbitrary points as you do not control where the solver puts the mesh points, at least after the first mesh refinement. This task is widely known as **interpolation**. It would probably work best if you use a cubic spline interpolation, or even higher degree splines, as the solver uses a high-order collocation method that presupposes that the ODE is smooth of a similar order.

Comment: The arbitrary points or my dataset are exactly at mesh points and I think I do not need interpolation. I do control my dataset and at each iteration, I update them which is not shown here. My dataset is a function table at exactly the mesh points.

Comment: That would only be the case if you construct your own BVP solver. The provided solver `bvp4c` represents its solution internally as a piecewise polynomial function over a mesh that may contain some, but not all nodes of the mesh of the initial guess. The mesh will change in each internal iteration of the solver. The collocation method also needs to evaluate the slope function at points `x` between the mesh nodes. You will need to generate additional values from the function table, and however you do it, this will be some form of interpolation.

Comment: That makes sense now. Then fitting my dataset to a curve (curve fitting) would definitely work with the current 'bvp4c' but I do not like this way. I know I can solve it numerically using the finite element or finite difference methods but I do not like it that way, either. I will check interpolation. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Curve fitting of $f$ can lead to simpler, faster expressions (table look-up can be expensive) and might also smooth some random errors in the data. But then there is over- and underfitting. Spline interpolation in the simplest case is just drawing lines between the data points.

Comment: I totally agree that curve fitting is not a good choice for my case. Is this Spline interpolation more accurate and computationally efficient or solving the problem from scratch using numerical methods such as FEM and FD?

Comment: Finite difference, finite element, collocation are all based, partially or fully, on the idea of piecewise polynomial interpolation. Splines are piecewise polynomial interpolation functions that minimize the variation of the resulting function or some derivative of it. So there is not really a generally better variant, at least if the methods have the same error order. // Computing the polynomial coefficients requires the solution of a banded linear system. Evaluation, especially ordered multi-point evaluation, should then be quite competitive.